# How does ArgoCD sync/update a updated helm chart under the hood?

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, gitops

our team right now is using helm chart to deploy services to k8s cluster, and ArgoCD to sync the helm chart modification to k8s cluster.

My question is that, when ArgoCD performs a helm chart sync, what action does it do under the hood? **does it use the command "helm upgrade" to do it?** or else?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argo does not perform a `helm install` or `helm upgrade` of sorts; it is more closely related to a `helm template <cmd+opts> | kubectl apply -f -`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into the concept of GitOps.

> Argo CD is responsible for pulling updated code from Git repositories
> and deploying it directly to Kubernetes resources.
> (quoted from https://codefresh.io/learn/argo-cd/)

Answer (score -1):

I think best way is to package the chart into a CR instances in your env and then give argocd credentials to access the charts

The trick is how would you give argocd credentials and also if you have multiple charts how do sync all in one go